# C++ Default Argument Error

Tags: c++, default-arguments

Any Idea why this error is coming up at compile time?

```
ComplexNumber.cpp:21: error: default argument given for parameter 1 of ‘void ComplexNumber::print(std::ostream&) const’
ComplexNumber.h:17: error: after previous specification in ‘void ComplexNumber::print(std::ostream&) const’
```

Here is my code at those certain areas:

ComplexNumber.cpp

```
21    void ComplexNumber::print(ostream & out = cout) const {
```

ComplexNumber.h

```
17    void print(ostream & out = cout) const;
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: wouldn't it be more straight forward to use `operator<<` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should only specify the default parameter in the function declaration, i.e. in the header. You implementation should look something like this:

```
void ComplexNumber::print(ostream & out) const { ..... }
```